# How can I shortern if, elif, elif statements in Python

Tags: python

How can I make the following code short:

```
q=0.34
density=''
```

```
    if abs(q) ==0:
        density='Null'
    elif abs(q) <= 0.09:
        density='negligible'
    elif abs(q) <= 0.49:
        density='slight'
    elif abs(q) <= 0.69:
        density='strong'
    else:
        density='very strong'
    print(q,", ", density)
```

Expected output :

```
0.34, 'slight'
```

I think there is a solution by using `dictionaries`,

Any help from your side will be highly appreciated !

Comment: Actually, sorry, I lied - I missed the `<=` stuff. My bad. Dictionaries will be a poor case here, as they want specific keys, not ranges.

Comment: So you *could* do this with pattern matching and guards, but it would be more involved syntax and gain you almost nothing. I think your code as-is is actually good. The one thing I'd change is to bind `abs(q)` to a value first, so you're not re-doing the call on every line.

Comment: @EdwardPeters the value of `q` changes because my code will be used inside a `function`

Comment: Yeah, but it's not changing over the course of this block of code, yeah? Just bind `q` to a variable on the first line and use that. If the function is called with a different `q`, that line that assigns the variable will run with the updated value.

Comment: @EdwardPeters Thanks, my current code works, but I want to make nicer, does it look like good, clean and nice like it is?

Comment: It's fine except for the repeated call I mentioned. Even that's not awful, as `abs` should be a pure function (no side effects), but it would still be cleaner not to call it every time. To understand why, pretend that instead of taking an absolute value, `abs` queried the user for an input - the way you have it written would ask them again on every branch of the `if`. I know that's not what you're doing, but it's still better to code to that consistent style. Also, it's generally bad to have constants like that hard-code - if you want to be really good, bind them as constants somewhere.

Comment: Thank you @EdwardPeters, can you please convert your comment into an answer with a piece of code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
q=0.34
density=''
conditions = [
(0,'null'),
(0.09, 'negligible'),
(0.49, 'slight'),
(0.69, 'strong')
]
# loops through the conditions and check if they are smaller
# if they are, immediately exit the loop, retaining the correct density value
for limit, density in conditions:
    if q <= limit:
        break
# this if statement checks if its larger than the last condition
# this ensures that even if it never reached any condition, it doesn't
# just output the last value
if q > conditions[-1][0]:
    density = 'very strong'

print(q,", ", density)
```

of course if you want to make it more short :)
(assuming q is always smaller than 9999)

```
q=0.34
c = [(0,'null'),(0.09,'negligible'),(0.49,'slight'),(0.69,'strong'), (9999,'very strong')]
print(q,',',[j for i,j in c if abs(q)<=i][0])
```

EDIT: fixed mistake in answer noted by Khaled DELLAL

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just we have to add `abs` in the last line `print(q,',',[j for i,j in c if abs(q)<=i][0])`

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like that:

```py
def f(q):
    # List of your limits values and their density values
    values = [(0, "Null"), (0.09, "negligible"), (0.49, "slight"), (0.69, "strong")]
    # Default value of the density, i.e. your else statement
    density = "very strong"

    # Search the good density and stop when it is found
    for (l, d) in values:
        if abs(q) <= l:
            density = d
            break

    print(q, ", ", density)
```

I think the comments are explicit enough to explain the code but don't hesitate to ask if it is not clear.

Comment: I would suggest using a list of tuples rather than two lists, just for the sake of making it visually obvious what limit is associated with what name.

Comment: Yes it's true, I modify accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Coded up a solution here which instead of checking all the if-else statements, it rather loops through an array of values and finds in which space the input value belongs:

```py
import numpy as np
vals = [0, 0.09,0.49,0.69,]
msgs = ['Null', 'negligible', 'slight', 'strong', 'very strong']

q=0.5
density=''

def calc_density(q:float) -> str:
    are_greater_than = q>np.array(vals)
    if all(are_greater_than): bools = -1
    else: bools = np.argmin(are_greater_than)
    return msgs[bools]

for q in [-0.1, 0.0, 0.2, 0.07, 0.8]:
    print(q, calc_density(q))

# >>> -0.1 Null
# >>> 0.0 Null
# >>> 0.2 slight
# >>> 0.07 negligible
# >>> 0.8 very strong
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: having the values and descriptions dissociated in two lists is (1) cumbersome to edit, (2) easy to error while editing, (3) hard to read back when reading the source code. 
A dictionary, or even a list of 2-tuples, each tuple with the threshold and description would be better.

Answer (score 1):

If this is used in a single place, this code is good as is, and there is nothing wrong with it.

If there are more places in which you want to assign a numeric range to a string, you can use a function or a class to do it,in a way that you can encode the values in a better way.

For example,a  simple, configurable function to do the same would be:

```
def _range_to_str(ranges, value):
    for threshold, description in ranges.items():
         if value <= threshold:
              return description
    raise ValueError(f"{value} out of range for {ranges}")

densities = {0: "", 0.09:"negligible", 0.49: "slight", ...}

def density_description(value):
    return _range_to_str(densities, value)
```